# ACS Setup For Mobile App

Tags: mobile, access-control, adfs, acs

I'm writing a mobile app that connects to Azure web services that use ACS access control for authentication.  The mobile app is going to be a new version of a website that already exists.  The website is already setup in ACS to connect to the web services.

Do I need to create a new entry in the ACS portal for the mobile app or can I just re-use the entry that the website has?  If I create a new entry, what would I put in the realm and return URL?  Mobile apps don't use URLs so I'm confused.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ACS supports a jsnotify protocol which basically will fire a JavaScript event that the host can listen. However this only works on Windows Phone. The other option you have is to poll the InApp browser (webview) until the URL is equal to whatever you put on the return url. Then inspect the result of the page to get the token, but that's not very easy. The truth is that ACS has not been updated for years and they are behind on mobile scenarios. You will probably spend a week or so trying to get something to work.

You can look at other services like [Auth0](https://auth0.com) (disclaimer: I work at Auth0) which support the same protocol ACS supports (Ws-Fed) and have native support for lots of platforms (ios, wp, windows8, android, xamarin, etc.).

Comment: Thanks woloski.  I'm actually making a Xamarin app for iOS and Android.  Based on what you said it sounds like there is no way I can authenticate against ACS => Ws-Fed in Xamarin (unless I use the webview hack).  Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. The thing is ws-fed is not a mobile-ready protocol. There is a way to wokaround it in ACS using the webview + polling + inspect the webpage and look for the token.

Comment: BTW, Auth0 provides a Xamarin component https://components.xamarin.com/view/Auth0Client